# Display Icon Fonts are not correct at Live Website

Tags: css, fonts, icons, show, glyphicons

I develop the website https://redeagle-it.de/ At homepage there are some blue squares and there's an Icon Font in it. Everything is fine at my Development-Server: https://re123.redeagle-it.de/ but not at Live.

**I have no idea what the problem is?** I've made the font via [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/)

Live
[image]

Dev
[image]

Comment: Clear the cache and live server, and try.

Comment: cleared cache more than 100x times ... no effect

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS paths are wrong in the live server. That's why Stylesheets are not loading.

Try setting the absolute URLs for the CSS paths and load them to test it.

Comment: stylesheets are loading .. otherwise you can't see the bootstrap template and styles-stuff

Comment: I am not sure what happen to current live site. External scripts are blocked. Also I changed the CSS path of dev to live earlier and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

At http://www.redeagle-it.de I'll see the Icon Font, not at http://redeagle-it.de.

Now I've made a 301 redirect from http:// to http://www. via htaccess and now it works.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^redeagle-it\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.redeagle-it.de/$1 [R=301]
```